# how can set properties swagger to list of String List<String>

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, swagger

I am trying to create springDoc swagger documentation, and I'd like to represent a data like this
**`List<String> elements;`**
having some properties like minSize and MaxSize / minLength Max length for values in list.
I tried with this

```java
@Schema(required = true, minLength = 12,maxLength = 20)
List<String> elements;
```

and

```java
@Size(min=10,max=20)
List<String> elements;
```

result:

```json
"Products": {
  "title": "Products",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "elements": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea To have this result :

```json
"Products": {
    "title": "Products",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "elements": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "string",
                "maxLength": 20,
                "minLength": 5
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `@ArraySchema` is what you are looking for as follows:

```java
@ArraySchema(minItems = 12, maxItems = 20)
List<String> elements;
```

`@Schema` is to be used for non-array elements and `@ArraySchema` is to be used for array elements. Both cannot coexist.

Comment: the question related to the min/max length of items *inside* the list, and not to the minimal and maximal items of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need :

```
@JsonProperty(value = "elements")
@ArraySchema(arraySchema = @Schema(description = "elements of the request"))
@NotEmpty(message = "Elements cannot be empty")  
private Set<@Pattern(regexp = "^\\d{12,20}$", message = "Invalid element no, valid element nos are between 12 and 20 digits") String> elements = new HashSet<>();
```